# Error connected with biber while compiling pdf

Tags: biblatex, errors, biber

I'm writing my thesis in latex, and I made my own .sty file with packages. In document preamble I only included biblatex package which makes this error:

```
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
               .
l.7 \usepackage
           [backend=biber,
I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
               .
l.7 \usepackage
           [backend=biber,
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

This is my .sty file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{wbmilszablon}
[09.06.2017 v0.6 - paczka LaTeX dla mojego uzytku]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{palatino,eulervm}               % czcionka Palatino oraz Euler
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                % wymagane do działania czcionki Palatino
\linespread{1.05}                       % interlinia, 1.05 ze wzgledu na czcionke Palatino


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % kodowanie dokumentu
\usepackage[english,polish]{babel}          % kroj czcionki w jezyku polskim i angielskim
\usepackage[MeX]{polski}                    % słownik łamania wyrazow w jezyku polskim


\usepackage{xcolor}                 % kolory hiperłaczy
\usepackage[unicode,                    % hiperłacza
        hidelinks,
        colorlinks,
        linkcolor={red!50!black},
        citecolor={blue!50!black}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}                   % cudzysłowy
\usepackage{graphicx}                   % pakiet graficzny, wymagany do wstawiania rysunkow
\usepackage{float}                      % rysunki w zadanym miejscu
\usepackage{enumitem}                   % spis tresci i listy
\usepackage{indentfirst}                    % aktywne pierwsze wciecie w akapicie
\usepackage{etoolbox}                   % pakiet umozliwiajacy edycje domyslnych komend
\usepackage{amsmath}                    % pakiet matematyczny
\usepackage{bm}                     % dla pogrubionych i pochylonych czcionek w srodowisku matematycznym
\usepackage[a4paper,                    % wymiary strony
        left=3.5cm,
        right=2cm,
        top=2cm,
        bottom=2cm,
        includefoot=false,
        includehead=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,              % otoczenie podpisow tabel i rysunkow
        justification=RaggedRight,
        singlelinecheck=false,
        format=hang,
        labelfont=bf,
        labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{titling}                    % tytulowanie
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\newcommand\blankpage{                              % komenda dla pustej strony
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage}


\DeclareQuoteAlias{croatian}{polish}                            % deklaracja cudzysłowow


\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*),leftmargin=1.25cm}                % odsuniecie wypunktowania
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=-,labelsep=0.4cm,leftmargin=1.25cm}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=-,labelsep=0.4cm,leftmargin=0.6cm}


\setlength\parindent{1.25cm}                                % wciecie 1.25cm
\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\parindent}


\addto\captionspolish{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Rys.}}         % zmiana domyslnego podpisu dla rysunku


\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{table}}           % zmiana domyslnej numeracji dla rysunkow itp.
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}                                   % pagina

\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
   \fancyhf{}                                           % empty header and footer
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}                       % ho header line
   \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}                       % not footer line
   \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}                              % like fancy style
}
```

this is my preamble:

```
% Preambuła_start
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{mwart}                     % rozmiar czcionki, druk dwustronny, klasa mwart
\usepackage{wbmilszablon}                               % szablon z paczkami
% Bibliografia_start
\usepackage[backend=biber,
            hyperref=true,
            url=false,
            isbn=false,
            doi=false,
            backref=true,
            citestyle=numeric-comp,
            sorting=nty]{biblatex}                      % biblatex z funkcjami
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}                   % w spisie literatury nazwiska na poczatku
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,thesis,report]{title}{#1}   % styl tytułow wybranych rekordow (brak italic)
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}                                   % brak makra "Wyd" przed wydawnictwem w spisie literatury
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}         % dwukropek po autorach w spisie literatury
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\addspace}     % brak "and" przed ostatnim autorem w spisie literatury
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}
\addbibresource{bibliografia/bibliografia.bib}      % sciezka do bibliografii .bib
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I think the problem is with your package rather than related to `biblatex`.  A sufficient [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) seems to be `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{wbmilszablon} \begin{document} Foo \end{document}` although I can't immediately spot anything amiss with the `.sty` file supplied

Comment: @DaiBowen it's a malformed date

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed, I spent a while working that out before coming to post an answer and seeing yours.  My comment was from the review queue so I'm not sure if I opened it before you'd posted or just failed to check the number of answers given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\ProvidesPackage{wbmilszablon}
[09.06.2017 v0.6 - paczka LaTeX dla mojego uzytku]
```

the date has to be in the form `2017/06/09` or if you have the very latest LaTeX release you may also use `2017-06-09`.

Comment: Thank you! This was super helpfull and everything is working now ;)!  I've second question, I'm using caption package, I want to have word breaking algorithm inside my caption. The caption documentation says to use RaggedRight option with ragged2e package. As you can see I set those options in my .sty file, but even that, the word breaking algorithm does not works: http://imgur.com/Fmdkqo9

Comment: @MajkelTMB best to ask that as a new question, not in comments (you can check with `\showhyphens` whether tex knows how o hyphenate that word